Problem with Knight's Tour in DLV/ASP with Restricted Moves. DLV/.PLAN
I am working on solving the Knight's Tour problem using DLV and a custom plan. The board is a 4x4 grid, and two specific cells (4,1 and 4,4) are excluded from the tour. The knight starts at position (3,1) with 15 moves remaining(can be modified).
chessboard created as reference
Files involved:
.dlv: Defines the possible moves for the knight, the board positions, and other rules.
%first archive
% positions/cells
posicion(1,1).posicion(1,2).posicion(1,3).posicion(1,4).
posicion(2,1).posicion(2,2).posicion(2,3).posicion(2,4).
posicion(3,1).posicion(3,2).posicion(3,3).posicion(3,4).
          posicion(4,2).posicion(4,3).

% defining a horse
caballo(caballo).

%Defining all possible movements (40 movements in total)
% Moves of (1,1) etc
movimiento(1,1,2,3).
movimiento(1,1,3,2).


.plan (restrictions): Includes various constraints such as "not visited" and "not occupied" to ensure valid moves:
%2nd archive
% Defining fluents
fluents:
    
    en(B, X, Y) requires posicion(X, Y). % the knight is in the cell (X, Y)
    
    % occupied cells
    ocupado(X, Y) requires posicion(X, Y). %securing that occupied cells are definided

    visitado(X, Y) requires posicion(X, Y). % cell(X, y) is already visited 

    

actions:
    mover(B, X1, Y1, X2, Y2) requires posicion(X2, Y2), en(B, X1, Y1),  movimiento(X1, Y1, X2, Y2),not visitado(X2,Y2),not ocupado(X2,Y2).

    

always:

    inertial en(B, X, Y). % knight position is inertial
    
    caused en(B, X2, Y2) after mover(B, X1, Y1, X2, Y2). % update the knight position
        caused -en(B, X1, Y1) after mover(B, X1, Y1, X2, Y2). % removes the previous position
    caused visitado(X, Y) after en(B, X, Y). % mark the cell as 'visit' after move to it

    

    % knight can only move to a cell that are not occupied and unvisited
    
    executable mover(B, X1, Y1, X2, Y2) if en(B, X1, Y1), not ocupado(X2,   Y2), not visitado(X2, Y2).
    noConcurrency.


.plan: Contains the knight's configuration, including initial position and goal.
%3rd archive
i
nitially:
    en(caballo, 3, 1). % Defining the initial cell

goal:
    en(caballo, 3, 1) ? (15) % defining the the where the last move is going to end and in how many steps

Execute in console with a dlv.exe:
dlv caballo.txt caballo-AF.plan caballo-conf.plan -FP
I've checked that (1,2) is valid in the move rules, but it still doesn't get visited in the 15-move solution, notice that in STATE 12 it supposed jump into 1,2 but did 4,3 instead.
RESULT:
STATE 0: en(caballo,3,1)
ACTIONS: mover(caballo,3,1,4,3)
STATE 1: visitado(3,1), -en(caballo,3,1), en(caballo,4,3)
ACTIONS: mover(caballo,4,3,2,2)
STATE 2: visitado(4,3), -en(caballo,4,3), en(caballo,2,2)
ACTIONS: mover(caballo,2,2,1,4)
STATE 3: visitado(2,2), -en(caballo,2,2), en(caballo,1,4)
ACTIONS: mover(caballo,1,4,3,3)
STATE 4: en(caballo,3,3), visitado(1,4), -en(caballo,1,4)
ACTIONS: mover(caballo,3,3,2,1)
STATE 5: visitado(3,3), -en(caballo,3,3), en(caballo,2,1)
ACTIONS: mover(caballo,2,1,1,3)
STATE 6: visitado(2,1), -en(caballo,2,1), en(caballo,1,3)
ACTIONS: mover(caballo,1,3,3,4)
STATE 7: en(caballo,3,4), visitado(1,3), -en(caballo,1,3)
ACTIONS: mover(caballo,3,4,4,2)
STATE 8: en(caballo,4,2), visitado(3,4), -en(caballo,3,4)
ACTIONS: mover(caballo,4,2,2,3)
STATE 9: en(caballo,2,3), visitado(4,2), -en(caballo,4,2)
ACTIONS: mover(caballo,2,3,1,1)
STATE 10: visitado(2,3), -en(caballo,2,3), en(caballo,1,1)
ACTIONS: mover(caballo,1,1,3,2)
STATE 11: visitado(1,1), -en(caballo,1,1), en(caballo,3,2)
ACTIONS: mover(caballo,3,2,2,4)
STATE 12: en(caballo,2,4), visitado(3,2), -en(caballo,3,2)
ACTIONS: mover(caballo,2,4,4,3)
STATE 13: en(caballo,4,3), visitado(2,4), -en(caballo,2,4)
ACTIONS: mover(caballo,4,3,3,1)
STATE 14: en(caballo,3,1), visitado(4,3), -en(caballo,4,3)
ACTIONS: (no action)
STATE 15: en(caballo,3,1), visitado(3,1)
PLAN: mover(caballo,3,1,4,3); mover(caballo,4,3,2,2); mover(caballo,2,2,1,4); mover(caballo,1,4,3,3); mover(caballo,3,3,2,1); mover(caballo,2,1,1,3); mover(caballo,1,3,3,4); mover(caballo,3,4,4,2); mover(caballo,4,2,2,3); mover(caballo,2,3,1,1); mover(caballo,1,1,3,2); mover(caballo,3,2,2,4); mover(caballo,2,4,4,3); mover(caballo,4,3,3,1); (no action)

I increased the number of moves to 18, but the knight violates constraints when doing so.
I'm using not visited(X, Y) and not occupied(X, Y) to enforce valid moves, but it seems the knight is not adhering to these constraints properly.
STATE 0: en(caballo,3,1)
ACTIONS: mover(caballo,3,1,4,3)
STATE 1: visitado(3,1), -en(caballo,3,1), en(caballo,4,3)
ACTIONS: mover(caballo,4,3,2,2)
STATE 2: visitado(4,3), -en(caballo,4,3), en(caballo,2,2)
ACTIONS: mover(caballo,2,2,1,4)
STATE 3: visitado(2,2), -en(caballo,2,2), en(caballo,1,4)
ACTIONS: mover(caballo,1,4,3,3)
STATE 4: en(caballo,3,3), visitado(1,4), -en(caballo,1,4)
ACTIONS: mover(caballo,3,3,2,1)
STATE 5: visitado(3,3), -en(caballo,3,3), en(caballo,2,1)
ACTIONS: mover(caballo,2,1,1,3)
STATE 6: visitado(2,1), -en(caballo,2,1), en(caballo,1,3)
ACTIONS: mover(caballo,1,3,3,4)
STATE 7: en(caballo,3,4), visitado(1,3), -en(caballo,1,3)
ACTIONS: mover(caballo,3,4,4,2)
STATE 8: en(caballo,4,2), visitado(3,4), -en(caballo,3,4)
ACTIONS: mover(caballo,4,2,2,3)
STATE 9: en(caballo,2,3), visitado(4,2), -en(caballo,4,2)
ACTIONS: mover(caballo,2,3,1,1)
STATE 10: visitado(2,3), -en(caballo,2,3), en(caballo,1,1)
ACTIONS: mover(caballo,1,1,3,2)
STATE 11: visitado(1,1), -en(caballo,1,1), en(caballo,3,2)
ACTIONS: mover(caballo,3,2,2,4)
STATE 12: en(caballo,2,4), visitado(3,2), -en(caballo,3,2)
ACTIONS: mover(caballo,2,4,4,3)
STATE 13: en(caballo,4,3), visitado(2,4), -en(caballo,2,4)
ACTIONS: mover(caballo,4,3,2,2)
STATE 14: visitado(4,3), -en(caballo,4,3), en(caballo,2,2)
ACTIONS: mover(caballo,2,2,1,4)
STATE 15: visitado(2,2), -en(caballo,2,2), en(caballo,1,4)
ACTIONS: mover(caballo,1,4,3,3)
STATE 16: en(caballo,3,3), visitado(1,4), -en(caballo,1,4)
ACTIONS: mover(caballo,3,3,1,2)
STATE 17: en(caballo,1,2), visitado(3,3), -en(caballo,3,3)
ACTIONS: mover(caballo,1,2,3,1)
STATE 18: en(caballo,3,1), -en(caballo,1,2), visitado(1,2)
PLAN: mover(caballo,3,1,4,3); mover(caballo,4,3,2,2); mover(caballo,2,2,1,4); mover(caballo,1,4,3,3); mover(caballo,3,3,2,1); mover(caballo,2,1,1,3); mover(caballo,1,3,3,4); mover(caballo,3,4,4,2); mover(caballo,4,2,2,3); mover(caballo,2,3,1,1); mover(caballo,1,1,3,2); mover(caballo,3,2,2,4); mover(caballo,2,4,4,3); mover(caballo,4,3,2,2); mover(caballo,2,2,1,4); mover(caballo,1,4,3,3); mover(caballo,3,3,1,2); mover(caballo,1,2,3,1)

Any help or suggestions to resolve this would be greatly appreciated!
